# Graph and ipywidget cannot be in same code cell when using %matplotlib notebook

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I want to make a figure and interactively change it with ipywidgets.
When I use `%matplotlib notebook`, the widget call needs to be in a separate code cell, which is odd. Here is the code that doesn't work

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
%matplotlib notebook

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax1 = plt.subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax1.set_xlim(-5,5)
ax1.set_ylim(-5,5)
circ = Circle((0,0), radius=1)
ax1.add_patch(circ)

def change_radius(r=1):
    circ.set_radius(r)

from ipywidgets import interact
interact(change_radius, r=(1.0, 5))
```

This only works when the last two lines are in a separate code cell, but then the widget is separated from the graph by the code cell. Does anybody know how to get it to work in one code cell with `%matplotlib notebook` ?

Comment: I think this is a limitation of the current implementation (which does not directly use ipywidgets but injects a good bit of custom js) which does not play as well with the display machinery as it should.

Comment: That's what I was worried about. Is this something that can be changed, or does that require a complete overhaul of the current implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the figure explicitly using `display(fig)` in `change_radius()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from IPython.display import display
%matplotlib notebook

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax1 = plt.subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax1.set_xlim(-5,5)
ax1.set_ylim(-5,5)
circ = Circle((0,0), radius=1)
ax1.add_patch(circ)

def change_radius(r=1):
    circ.set_radius(r)
    display(fig)

from ipywidgets import interact
interact(change_radius, r=(1.0, 5))
```

Comment: @MarkBakker No problem! make sure you also check out the ipywidget examples at their github repo. They are a useful source of info.